# S3 browser upload with meta deta

Tags: html, laravel, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to upload files directly to S3 from browser.
Generally it works. But now I want to add meta deta with it as well.
Meta data includes file type, user name etc.

Comment: Please add details.

Comment: If you can do it without metadata what's the issue with adding metadata? The same API call that accepts the file also accepts metadata